# The Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive cannot be found

Tags: c#, wcf

Okay, I've spent the day looking at this error and all of the posts re, but I still can't seem to find where I've gone wrong.  I can communicate with the web service find from an external web service client but I cannot browse the .svc file from within VS or from IIS.  I'm publishing to a mapped drive on IIS 6 server, .NET 4.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Web.config

```
<services>
      <service name="BiteSizeLearningWS.TranscriptService">

        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="BiteSizeLearningWS.iServiceInterface" />


      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
      </serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <standardEndpoints>
          <webHttpEndpoint>
              <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" faultExceptionEnabled="false"></standardEndpoint>
          </webHttpEndpoint>
      </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Service.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="BiteSizeLearningWS.TranscriptService" %>
```

IserviceInterface.cs

```
namespace BiteSizeLearningWS
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface iServiceInterface
    ...
```

Comment: You try put address attribute in endpoint element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.  My mistake was that the classname that implemented the service interface did not match my service name in my svc file.  I didn't realize that they had to match.

I.e.
My service name was:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="BiteSizeLearningWS.TranscriptService" %>
```

But my implementation was:

```
public class TranscriptServiceLibrary : iServiceInterface
```

Rather than

```
public class TranscriptService : iServiceInterface
```

Sorry, everyone.  I obviously didn't include the one file that everyone needed to determine the problem.  Thank you for all of your input.

Comment: This hint took me to the solution, great!